# How do I rent a small bus in Buenos Aires?

Tags: car-rentals, buses, rental, buenos-aires

I want to rent a small bus (the one that still counts as a regular car) for 8 people to go from Buenos Aires to Córdoba for a week. Bonus points if the vehicle is the crummy almost falling apart kind. I´m googling around and the results are very confusing. I´m not very good with computers.

Anyone who has done anything like this, can you please recommend me a specific car rental service to go to? Or perhaps a local Craigslist kind of thing? I can speak Spanish.

Comment: No, it´s return.

Comment: Wait, you *want* the 'crummy almost falling apart' kind?

Comment: And are you driving, or do you want a driver for the trip?

Comment: Are you looking to break down along the way, or is this more for a photo theme for the grand kids?